# Serializer complains about request data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to append some data to the request, so I did the following:

```
data = {'my_data': 1, **request.data}
...
serializer = MySerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

But the serializer is complaining about the fields not being in the correct format:

> "Not a valid string."

It says the same on all of them. Makes sense because I see it's creating a dict filled with lists:

```
{'attr1':[1], 'attr2':[2], ..., 'my_data':1}
```

What doesn't make sense is that this works just fine:

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

Even though the `QueryDict` object has all fields wrapped in a list too

I also tried the following:

```
data = {'my_data': [1], **request.data}
```

But now it also complains about the new field.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Just to clarify, a workaround would be to just unwrap all items:

```
data = {**{k: v for k, v in request.data.items()}}
```

But why does the serializer behave differently with normal dicts and with `QueryDict`s?

Comment: Why not add the `my_data` to the `request.data` directly and pass it to the serializer then?

Answer (score 0):

QueryDict is not just a dictionary with field values as lists, but a complex structure with overridden methods that define how it behaves for certain operators. Below is the getitem method defined in **MultiValueDict**, which is the base class for **QueryDict**.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    """
    Return the last data value for this key, or [] if it's an empty list;
    raise KeyError if not found.
    """
    try:
        list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
    except KeyError:
        raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
    try:
        return list_[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return []
```

With this, even though the values for keys are lists, when you try to get an item from a QueryDict like

```
my_query_dict[my_key]
```

The last item in the list is returned. However, when you build a new dictionary using ** on the query dict, what you get is just a regular dictionary with its items as lists, so when you get the value of a key, you get back a list. To exemplify, let my_query_dict be a QueryDict instance, holding value [1] for key 'a'.

```
my_query_dict['a'] # returns 1
{**my_query_dict}['a'] # returns [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some may say that messing with `request.data` is not "proper way". But if you still want it then better create mutable copy of QueryDict:

```py
data = request.data.copy()
data['my_data'] = 1
```

`rest_framework` has many mixins/generics/builtin-views that simply initialize serializers as `SerializerCls(data=request.data, instance=something_or_none, context={'request': view.request, 'view': view}`. And if you are using same serializer in more than one view, then it's better to make your serializer "smart" instead of modifying each view.

"Smart" serializer should calculate all extra data from "raw `request.data`/`request`". "Partially smart" serializers might require changes to the view.

If you just need to set a custom value to some model field on save, then you can change view's method `perform_update`/`perform_create` (if you are using `GenericAPIView`-s)

```py
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(my_data=1)
```

If you really need this custom data accounted during validation: you might use context:

```py
class MySerializer(...):
    def validate(self, data):
        if 'my_data' in self.context:
            data['my_data'] = self.context['my_data']
        if data.get('my_data'): 
            perform_some_extra_validation(data)
        return data

serializer = MySerializer(data=data, context={'my_data': 1})
serializer.is_valid()
# for ModelView-s you can change context by modifying `get_serializer_context` method
```

If you can calculate `my_data` dynamically from `request`, or from `request.user`, then:

- You can do it right in the `serializer.validate` by using context:

```py
class MySerializer(...):
    def validate(self, data):
        if 'request' in self.context:
            data['my_data'] = build_my_data_from_request(self.context['request'])
        return data

serializer = MySerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
serializer.is_valid()

# in ModelView-s serializers are already initialized with 'request' in context
```

- Or you can use combination of context and `default` arg to the field:

```py
class MyDataDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.parent = serializer_field.parent

    def __call__(self):
        if 'request' in self.parent.context:
            return build_my_data_from_request(self.parent.context['request'])


class MySerializer(...):
    my_data = serializers.SomeField(default=MyDataDefault())


# if my_data should only be set during creation (not during update)
from rest_framework.serializers import CreateOnlyDefault

class AlternativeMySerializer(...):
    my_data = serializers.SomeField(default=CreateOnlyDefault(MyDataDefault()))


serializer = MySerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
serializer.is_valid()
# in ModelView-s serializers are already initialized with 'request' in context
```

If you are using `ModelViewSet` or other views based on `GenericAPIView`, then `get_serializer` already does something similar to `SerializerCls(data=request.data, instance=..., context={'request': request, 'view': self})`:

```py
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
        deserializing input, and for serializing output.
        """
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    ...


    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

Comment: Why is messing with request.data is not the proper way here? I am asking because I've used this approach several times before and have always considered that the clearest approach for such cases, and want to know if there are possible problems I haven't considered. Can you point to any articles or discussions on the topic?

Comment: In your case it's not that critical: your are not directly modifying `request.data` and only using it to create a new object. But what if `request.data` already contains `'my_data'` - should it be silently overriden or should error be raised? What if you are going to use serializer in a view that uses `rest_framework.mixins.*`? By default these mixins call `self.get_serializer(data=request.data)`. So it's "better" to design your serializers in a such way that they can calculate extra fields without external changes to data

Comment: Summary: if you are using serializer in a single view/place then your approach is fine (but maybe you should use `data = request.data.copy(); data['my_data'] = 1` because it's a QueryDict), and if your are using serializer in multiple views, or using  View-mixins/generic-view of a rest_framework then it's better to "create smarter serializer" (with custom `validate` method, or using classes with `set_context` as defaults for fields)